# Weird icon in system status area

Tags: icons, gnome-shell, 23.04

Using Ubuntu 23.04 with Gnome 44.1.

What does this lock with a warning triangle mean? No tooltips appear when hovering and none of the system menu entries show anything. I cannot find any documentation on Google.

[image]

Comment: Are you running any Gnome extensions? You might want to read [this thread](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/4798), as it suggests that poorly implemented extensions will force the display of this icon, which means "unsafe mode" has been enabled.

Comment: @richbl Only the ones that come with Ubuntu: Desktop Icons NG, Ubuntu AppIndicators and Ubuntu Dock. Turning those off doesn't make the icon go away.

Comment: @richbl See my answer. But without you saying it means unsafe mode, I wouldn't have figured it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, it turns out the culprit was...me, a few days ago. I was trying to get screen sharing to work and one answer somewhere suggested turning on unsafe mode. It's not clear that's what the icon means. @richbl's comment provided an answer to that. I turned off unsafe mode and it is gone.